# Prove that if $M$ is an $R-$ projective left module then $M/IM$ is an $R/I-$ projective left module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $I$ ba a two-sided ideal of a ring $R$ and $M$ be an $R-$ left module. Prove that if $M$ is an $R-$ projective left module then $M/IM$ is an $R/I-$ projective left module.

It is easy to see that $M/IM$ has the structure of $R/I-$module. I need some ideas to prove that $M/IM$ is an $R/I-$ projective left module.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well I see a similar result for right module http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813076/proving-that-p-pj-is-a-projective-right-module-over-r-j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that $\hom_{R/I}(M/IM,-) \cong \hom_R(M,U(-))$, where $U$ is the forgetful functor from $R/I$-modules to $R$-modules. Hence, this is a composition of two exact functors, hence exact.

Comment: (This answer has a clear duplicate, as noted above in comments, with four very satisfactory answers!)

Comment: In the "duplicate" Mariano ignores the forgetful functor (which most people do, although it is a central part of the argument).

Comment: In general, if $U$ is an exact functor, then its left adjoint (if it exists) preserves projective objects. Dually, the right adjoint of an exact functor preserves injective objects.